# A alternative for YAWcam that runs on Linux?

Tags: linux, webcam

I really like the [YAWcam](http://www.yawcam.com/) program, but unfortunately the developer hasn't made a Linux version. I'm looking for something similar that can:

- Get video from a webcam (duh)
- Allow me to do things when motion is detected (yawcam could take a video, a picture and run a .exe)
- Stream the webcam over my local LAN and if possible, the internet.

Other bonus features:

- Time lapse
- A scheduler which would allow me to schedule when to do certain things with the webcam.

Answer (score 1):

Motion is a useful terminal-based programme that should fit your needs. You can configure it to record a video, or images, or run a Bash script should motion be detected. In terms of scheduling you could run certain motion commands on a cron job.

Link: http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome

You can also stream it over a network. It's been around for years so should be in the standard repositories (eg. aptitude install motion or yum install motion). There's a guide on how to stream here which probably explains it better than I: http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-turn-your-webcam-into-a-motion-detecting-security-spy-camera-in-linux/

Comment: This looks somewhat promising. It doesn't support native streaming though, that I can tell (that article you link just has you upload the images to a separately managed FTP server).